# Error loading textures in monogame as non content files

Tags: xna, monogame

So basically I am making a small test game and I have a class that is used in the creation of all the entities in the game so I pass the class on to the object Player and run this code:

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{
  spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
  font = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("LCD");
  Player.Sprite = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Sprites/Player");
}
```

But for some reason, every time I attempt to debug and run it, it gives me an error which is weird because before the error did not show and it would run fine, here is what the error says:

> ContentLoadException was unhandled
>
> Could not load Sprites/Player asset as a non-content file!

I have a folder within the content folder named "Sprites" which does exactly as its names suggests, holds my sprites, and all the spelling is done correctly. I cannot figure out why this problem persist though.

Comment: Does it make a difference if the content path contains backward instead of forward slashes?

Answer (score 1):

It would be beneficial for me to know how you added the asset, where and which properties does it have configured, as well as the project structure to fully understand the root of the problem.

In any case, I have a blog post that may be useful for solving this problem, it was written using Monogame 3.2, if I remember correctly and explains how to create a really simple 2D game using XNA and Monogame.

From the series, what may be relevant in your case is the following block, explaining how to add an image asset to your game project. Keep in mind that the path to your sprite image will be different than the one in my example as you have the "Sprites" subfolder.

> You need to right click on the `Content` folder in the solution
>   explorer, choose the `Add Existing Item` option and then select the
>   image.
>
> Given that `Monogame` works in a different way than `XNA` when
>   managing the content pipeline, you are going to have to change the
>   properties of the image in order for the framework to recognize it. To
>   do this, select the image and navigate to it’s properties (F4 in
>   Visual Studio, or right click -> properties).
>
> Change it so that the image gets copied to the output folder if it is
>   newer.

[image]

You can find the full blog entry [here](http://nahuelianni.azurewebsites.net/02-background/).

Comment: Wow thanks your tutorial series is actually just I was looking for, I was planning on eventually adding a background after I fix this issue as well, anyways here's a screenshot of my problem + properties for my images, keep in mind it only shows when I debug and not at all while programming it myself like normal syntax error, both files have the same properties and no I do not plan on editing to Player.png for a while so I am not going to set it as "copy if newer".  https://www.dropbox.com/s/ujjo58jk07fzy6m/Monogame%20error.PNG?dl=0

Comment: If you do not set it to "Copy if newer", then the content pipeline will not be able to find it and load it on your game. Copy if newer means that if you change the image, the new one WILL be deployed, while setting it to "Do not copy" means it will never get deployed. Therefore, Monogame will not have it ready for when it needs to load it. That could work if it was XNA (don't truly remember now the details of it), but should not work with Monogame. It's not a preference thing, it's a requirement! The image needs to be deployed at some time for Monogame to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your string for errors. If I'm correct I saw this error a lot when I capitalized something that shouldn't have been.

String:  `"Sprites/Player"`

Comment: my string perfectly matches that of the file location and folder, I changed it however to escape the escape character foreword slash "\" so it now looks like this "Sprites\\Player" yet for some reason this still does not fix the main issue...

Comment: It should take the slash without a problem. Nahuel's answer is honestly what your looking for. Make sure you do that Copy if newer though! :D

Answer (score 0):

I Figured out the problem, you see I did not make the resource "Copy" at all and it needs to copy once to get it into the MonoGame project folder, Rookie mistake I know but at least this will help others who get stuck like me, Thank you everyone who attempted to help with this issues, I appreciate your time.